# Getting internal server error on Classic ASP page

Tags: asp-classic

I am trying the code snippet provided in http://www.bustercollings.com/source-code-samples/rss-asp-classic-source-code-example.asp in our server and am getting internal server error. I do not get any other errors.

What might be causing this error? Can someone test this code and see whether it works for you?

I have contacted the server team guys in our company and they are not at all helping me on this, as a simple ASP code works fine. They are saying that the problem is with the code. I feel there might be some components which is not installed in our server or some other unknown reason.

Can somebody please help me?

Thanks

Comment: Discover the exact error you're getting, and post that, along with the problematic code.

Comment: I do not know how to get the exact error.

Answer (score 1):

```
Set objHTTP = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP")
...
Set xmlRSSFeed = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.DomDocument.4.0")
```

You're creating two objects in the script. Depending on which version of Windows Server and/or ISS you're using these objects might not be installed (especially the second). I've ran into similar issues before. Trying making the 4.0 in the second CreateObject() call 3.0 (so it reads `Set xmlRSSFeed = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.DomDocument.3.0")`) it's more common for 2003 or earlier servers. They have up to version 6, and a few of them aren't straight #.0 version numbers either, so you'll likely need to do some testing/guessing/research.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. we have IIS 7.0 in our server. I thought the same as you. i tried removing all the lines after `Set objHTTP = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP")`. Even with this code I am getting internal server error.

Comment: You need to have your server admin turn detailed error messages on, or at least have them log in/remote in to the server and view the web page form there to get the exact error message instead of the generic one they have configured. Pretty much anything else is going to involve pure guesswork. =\

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it will definitely work:

```
Set xmlRSSFeed = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
```

instead of

```
Set xmlRSSFeed = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.DomDocument.4.0")
```